# how to put summary beside the detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

how can i create a layout like this:

```
store: xxx
-----------------------------------
| name  | sales    |               |
-----------------------------------
| aaaa  | 5000000  |    15000000   | <--(sub)total sales achieved each store
| bbbb  | 2000000  |    20000000   | <--sales target
| cccc  | 3500000  |        75 %   | <--percentage achieved
| dddd  | 2500000  |               |
| eeee  | 2000000  |               |
------------------------------------
```

basically i need to put the footer group right beside the detail band or right next to the 'actual' columns, not below it.
but is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using subreport.

Comment: ok then, i thought there's a way to do it without subreport.

Comment: I have resolved this type issue using subreport. If you have some other option , you can share here.